# in VBScript, is there a way for a value that occurs multiple times in a single array to be displayed by itself?

Tags: arrays, vbscript, iteration

I have an array that holds values that occur multiple times. Example:

```
dim myArray
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter a word: "
word1 = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter a word: "
word2 = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter a word: "
word3 = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter a word: "
word4 = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Enter a word: "
word5 = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
```

These inputs will be put into an array:

```
myArray = Array(word1, word2, word3, word4, word5)
```

Now what if the end user inputted ("steve", "steve", "doug", "doug", "steve")

If I do something like this:

```
for i = 1 to UBound(myArray)
    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine myArray(i) & ", "
next
```

My obvious result will be

```
"steve",
 "steve",
 "doug", 
 "doug", 
 "steve",
```

What if I wanted my result to only be

```
steve,
doug,
```

Any suggestions on what I could do to iterate over this array and display only a single occurrence of a value that appears more than once in an array.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) object. Either check the new addition with  `.Exists` or use the shorthand  to overwrite the items for duplicate keys.

**[dict_test.vbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028079/in-vbscript-is-there-a-way-for-a-value-that-occurs-multiple-times-in-a-single-a/35028161#35028161)**

```
Dim dWORDs : Set dWORDs = CreateObject ("Scripting.Dictionary")
dWORDs.CompareMode = 1
Dim prmpt : prmpt = "Enter a word: "

Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine prmpt
    dWORDs.Item(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine) = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine prmpt
    dWORDs.Item(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine) = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine prmpt
    dWORDs.Item(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine) = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine prmpt
    dWORDs.Item(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine) = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine prmpt
    dWORDs.Item(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine) = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine

Dim wrd
For Each wrd In dWORDs
    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "key: " & wrd & "    item: " & dWORDs.Item(wrd)
Next

dWORDs.RemoveAll: Set dWORDs = Nothing
```

That demonstrates the 'shorthand' method of either adding a new or overwriting an existing dictionary key without error. What remains is a list of the unique keys that can be enumerated through with a For .. Each statement.

Answer (score 1):

Asking **once** for each element in a loop, using Join(), and no fluff:

```
Option Explicit

Dim dWORDs : Set dWORDs = CreateObject ("Scripting.Dictionary")
dWORDs.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
Dim prmpt : prmpt = "Enter a word: "
Dim wrd

Do
  Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine prmpt
  wrd = Trim(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine())
  If "" = wrd Then Exit Do
  dWORDs.Item(wrd) = 0
Loop

WScript.Echo Join(dWORDs.Keys(), ",")
```